# Retrieve Most Current Row Out of MySql (based on date)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

What am i doing wrong? I am trying to take the most current row out of the db (based on date) and turn it into JSON. But this file just give me [].

```
$date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET['date']));

$myquery = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE week='$date'";
$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $myquery ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}



echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close();
```

?>

My data looks like this:

```
#id | week       | firstname | last name | score#

###1  |2015-03-06   | Bill      | Jones     | 25
 ###2  |2015-03-13   | Bill      | Jones     | 45

 ###3  |2015-03-06   | Dave      | Smith     | 32
 ###4  |2015-03-13   | Dave      | Smith     | 52

###5  |2015-03-06   | Mary      | Chu       | 28
 ###6  |2015-03-13   | Mary      | Chu       | 45
```

So for 3/13/2015 I want Bill, Dave and Mary's data to be turned into JSON. I don't want last weeks data, just the most current.

Comment: note - you are checking `if ( ! $myquery ) {`, but you should be checking `if ( ! $query ) {` as `$query` is where you are doing `mysql_query($myquery)`

Comment: foreach ($query as $row) { $data[$i]['id'] = row['id'] ; $i++} then $out = json_encode($data); assuming your query is returning the result.

Comment: Why don't people just use fetchAll http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php ?? Fetching one row at a time just ties up resources on your mysql server. OH, because you are still coding PHP4 with mysql instead of using PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that's exactly what you want.

And i'm afraid that i clearly don't understand what you exactly want to receive from db, that's why i add order by score:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $link);

$date = mysql_escape_string('2015-03-13');
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM mostCurrentRow WHERE week='$date' ORDER BY score DESC";
$query = mysql_query($myquery);
if ( ! $myquery ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_export($data);

echo json_encode($data);

mysql_close();

/*
will return:
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '4',
    'week' => '2015-03-13',
    'firstName' => 'Dave',
    'lastName' => 'Smith',
    'score' => '52',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'week' => '2015-03-13',
    'firstName' => 'Bill',
    'lastName' => 'Jones',
    'score' => '45',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '6',
    'week' => '2015-03-13',
    'firstName' => 'Mary',
    'lastName' => 'Chu',
    'score' => '45',
  ),
)[{"id":"4","week":"2015-03-13","firstName":"Dave","lastName":"Smith","score":"52"},{"id":"2","week":"2015-03-13","firstName":"Bill","lastName":"Jones","score":"45"},{"id":"6","week":"2015-03-13","firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Chu","score":"45"}]
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

the wrong thing that i can see in your code is the condition if(! $myquery), it should be if(!$query) or you can do it like this :

```
$query = mysql_query($myquery) or die(mysql_error());
```

also try to check if mysql_fetch_assoc($query) is returning anything or check if $date has values.

for your loop, i just wanted to share this:

you can also do it like this:

```
 for($data=array();$x=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);$data[]=$x);
```

=D

Answer (score -1):

change your query

```
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE week = STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')";
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query has $date inside the query text, rather then concatenated into it. It should look more like this:

```
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE week='".$date."' ORDER BY id";
```

Comment: [`The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) && [`When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: also, OP wants `So for 3/13/2015 I want Bill, Dave and Mary's data`, so `LIMIT 1` would only return `Bill`, not `Dave` or `Mary`.

Comment: That's a good point, I hadn't thought of that. That's just how I've always written php queries. 

Also, I missed that last line. My bad.